# Audio-Video Call webRTC and Ratchet (PHP WebSocket)

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I have my own chat system based on "My friends" and i have a list with online friends and i want when i click on a friend conversation to add the call functions but i don't know how to manage'it to have'it work. Can u help me pls? the conversation is with me (a) and user b (daniel) something like facebook calls for example, but here i have "localhost/chat/chat.php?room=Daniel "to be created when i click user b and all the call functions to work. (The code is written in PHP + Jquery and for audio call & video call i use (https://github.com/amirsanni/Video-Call-App) check the comm.js and comm.html files i guess from here i can mangete to have'it work..

Javascript Code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.contact', function(){

        $('.contact').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
          var username = $(this).attr('data-tousername');
          var to_user_id = $(this).data('touserid');
        showUserChat(to_user_id);

        history.pushState( null,null, '?chat='+username); //This is changing the url to ?room=username, but it dsn't do the trick..
});
function showUserChat(to_user_id){
    $.ajax({
        url:"pagini/chat/chat_action.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{to_user_id:to_user_id, action:'show_chat'},
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(response){
            $('#userSection').html(response.userSection);
            $('#aboutusr').html(response.aboutme);
            $('#conversation').html(response.conversation); 
            $('#unread_'+to_user_id).html('');
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: *"and i want when i click on a friend conversation to add the call functions"*... What is meant by "add the call functions" ?

Comment: The call functions are in "comm.js" file, u can find the file if u click that link.